# Error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException en java

Tags: java, array

Tengo un error en un ejercicio muy basico de java. Hace tiempo que no toco este lenguaje, y no se que es lo que pasa...(Lo siento si es una tonteria, pero es que no lo veo, de verdad).

Tengo un vector, de 100 posiciones, el cual relleno de forma ascendente y luego, hago una funcion para sumar las posiciones y mostrarlo por pantalla. Tengo que usar la funcion, por que el ejercicio es mas largo, pero tengo el problema aqui, en la linea 22.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //Esto es para un switch case
    System.out.println("Que opcion quieres.\n1Ejecutar por consola.\n2Ejecutar por dialogo.\n3Salir");
    InputStreamReader flujo = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader teclado = new BufferedReader(flujo);
    String opcion = teclado.readLine();
    //Creo el array de 100 posiciones
    int[] cienNumeros = new int[100];
    //Numeros es desde donde va a empezar, la posicion 0
    int numeros = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= cienNumeros.length; i++) {
        //*************AQUI ME DA EL ERROR EN LA CONSOLA, NO LO ENTIENDO
        cienNumeros[i] = numeros;
        numeros++;
        System.out.println(cienNumeros[i]);
    }

    int total = 0;
    total = suma(cienNumeros);
    System.out.println(total);
}

// Metodos
public static int suma(int[] cienNumeros) {
    int suma = 0;
    for (int h = 0; h <= cienNumeros.length; h++) {
        suma += cienNumeros[h];
    }
    return suma;
}
```

}

Muchas gracias a todos, se que sera una tonteria, pero es que no veo el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La longitude del array es 100 pero las posiciones siempre empiezan en 0, es decir van de 0 a 99.

Luego cuando i vale 100 tu condición `i <= cienNumeros.length` se cumple pero **no existe** tal posición y cuando se intenta ejecutar cienNumeros[100] te salta el error.

Prueba con esto:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < cienNumeros.length; i++) {
        cienNumeros[i] = numeros;
        numeros++;
        System.out.println(cienNumeros[i]);
    }
```

Comment: (Icono facepalm) Muchas gracias... no me daba cuenta del error, estaba buscando errores de sintaxis y no encontraba, y como estoy cansado de escribir for, no lo estaba mirando... Culpa mia. Muchas gracias.